# Update shared event as guest(GuestsCanModify) using google calendar api

Tags: c#, api, calendar

i managed to create an event, using the google calendar api and add attendees to it. But when i try to update the same event, now logged as a guest, i'm not able to update it. Even though i set GuestsCanModify value to true. Does anyone know if it's possible to update an event as a guest and get the changes replicated to the original event, the same way it already happens when you update the original event and it automatically update the event on the guest's calendar?
Below is a little piece o the code i used to create the event.

```
Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event event = new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event();
event.Summary = resCalendario.Titulo;
event.Location = resCalendario.Local;
event.Description = resCalendario.Obs;
event.GuestsCanModify = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Calendar API reference here is incomplete, but it looks like the guestsCanModify bit is not writable through the API.

This google groups post from 2011 has a reply by a Google employee stating that you cannot set that bit through the API: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-calendar-help-dataapi/5GEb29IEWrw

Here's the reference page for events: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events

The property table on that page includes entries for the two other guest permission settings (guestsCanInviteOthers, guestsCanSeeOtherGuests), but guestsCanModify is missing. In my own testing, I found that attempting to set this bit on an entry created or modified by an authorized user was ignored, which is consistent with that old forum post.